Could anyone explains Real-or-Random model?
I read the paper "Password-Key Based Authenticated Exchange in the Three-Party Setting," which mentions the security model RoR. It states that only test, send, and execute queries can be used, and reveal queries are not allowed. However, when I checked other papers that cite this one on Google Scholar, most of them use reveal queries to test the security of their protocols. Why is that?
PS. Sorry if this seems like a silly question, but I’m not very familiar with this area.
